# Cardinality Confusion: between users_roles and roles

Tags: database, entity, relationship, cardinality

I was designing a database as my practice and I came across a confusion where I am not sure the cardinality between a pair of my tables – users_roles, and roles

[image]

So I was wondering if you could break it down for me and explain how to think of it to be able to define the relationship. I've got quite a lot of these intermediate tables and they are just confusing me!

Additionally, I'd like to ask if I named my intermediate table correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what relationship you want to achieve.

`users` and `roles` tables are holding all the users and roles.
`users_roles` maps users with roles, or user id's with role id's. Both `user_id` and `role_id` are `FOREIGN KEY`s referencing `id` in the other tables as a `PRIMARY KEY`.

This is giving you a `one-many` relationship between `roles` and `user_roles` as one user can have multiple roles. You can also have `one-one` relationship if you make `role_id` `UNIQUE`, in this situation, a user will have only one role.
Hope this helps.